# @WebMvcTest No qualifying bean of type repository

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm writing a controller test where controller looks like

```
@RestController
public class VehicleController {
    @Autowired 
    private VehicleService vehicleService = null; 
    ... 

}
```

While the test class looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(VehicleController.class)
public class VehicleControllerTest {
    @Autowired 
    private MockMvc mockMvc = null;

    @MockBean 
    private VehicleService vehicleServie = null; 

    @Test
    public void test() {
       ...
    }
}
```

When I run this test it fails with the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.database.repositories.SomeOtherRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Here, `SomeOtherRepository` is not used in a given controller or service.

If I do `@MockBean` for `SomeOtherRepository` the test works but the same problem occurs for the rest of the repositories.

```
@MockBean private SomeOtherRepository someOtherRepository = null
...
# Bunch of other repositories
```

Ideally I should not be concerned about all the repositories except the one's I'm using. What am I missing here? How can I avoid writing bunch of `@MockBean`s?

Answer (score 4):

You have specified

```
@WebMvcTest(VehicleController.class)
```

which is fine, however you might find some beans from other dependencies, such as a custom `UserDetailsService`, some custom validation, or `@ControllerAdvice` that are also being brought in.

You can exclude these beans by using [exclude filters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html).

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = VehicleController.class, excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = CustomUserDetailsService.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your VehicleService depends on SomeOtherRepository, so you have to mock it too in your test class. Try adding:

```
@MockBean private SomeOtherRepository someOtherRepository
```

in your **VehicleControllerTest** class.